# unable to login after unstalling wine in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and want to uninstall `wine`. For this I used the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get purge wine*
```

and after that,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now I am unable to login to Ubuntu.

Comment: can you be more specific? What *exactly* do you see on screen? Where does the boot-process stop?

Comment: Try CTL+ALT+F1, login, and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`